# Failing to create services on Google Cloud Run with API using Java SDK

Tags: google-cloud-run

I create a Cloud Run client, however, couldn't find a way to list a service that is deployed with Cloud Run on GKE (for Anthos).

1. Create the client:

```
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
      credential.createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
      HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential);
      CloudRun.Builder builder = new CloudRun.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer);
      return builder.setApplicationName(applicationName)
                    .setRootUrl(cloudRunRootUrl)
                    .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2. try to list services:

```
 services = cloudRun.namespaces().services()
          .list("namespaces/default")
          .execute()
          .getItems();
```

My "hello" service is deploy on a GKE cluster under the namespace default. The above code doesn't work because the client always see "default" as project_id and complains about permission stuff. If I put the project_id rather than "default", permission errors are gone, but no services will be found.

I tried another project that does have Google fully-managed cloud run services, the same code returns result (with .list("namespaces/")).

How to access the service on GKE?

And my next question would be, how to programmatically create Cloud Run services on GKE?

**Edit - for creating a service**
As I couldn't figure out how to interact with Cloud Run on GKE, I took a step back to try fully managed one. The following code to create a service fails, and the error message just doesn't provide much useful insight, how to make it work?

```
    Service deployedService = null;
//    Map<String,String> annotations = new HashMap<>();
//    annotations.put("client.knative.dev/user-image","gcr.io/cloudrun/hello");

    ServiceSpec spec = new ServiceSpec();
    List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();
    containers.add(new Container().setImage("gcr.io/cloudrun/hello"));
    spec.setTemplate(new RevisionTemplate().setMetadata(new ObjectMeta().setName("hello-fully-managed-v0.1.0"))
                                           .setSpec(new RevisionSpec().setContainerConcurrency(20)
                                                                      .setContainers(containers)
                                                                      .setTimeoutSeconds(100)
                                                   )
                    );
    helloService.setApiVersion("serving.knative.dev/v1")
                .setMetadata(new ObjectMeta().setName("hello-fully-managed")
                                             .setNamespace("data-infrastructure-test-env")
//                                             .setAnnotations(annotations)
                 )
                .setSpec(spec)
                .setKind("Service");
    try {
        deployedService = cloudRun.namespaces().services()
            .create("namespaces/data-infrastructure-test-env",helloService)
            .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      response.add(e.toString());
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(response);
    }
```

Error message I got:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The request has errors",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request has errors",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
```

And the base_url is: `https://europe-west1-run.googleapis.com`

Comment: What's your cloud run root url? Is it in the same region as your deployment?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere it's https://europe-west1-run.googleapis.com. I also added it into my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite detailed (and is  about Java which I am no expert in) and there are actually too many questions in there (ideally, please ask only 1 question here). However, I'll try to answer a few things you asked:

First, Cloud Run (managed, and on GKE) both implement the Knative Serving API. I've explained this at https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-is-a-knative/ In fact, Cloud Run on GKE is just the open source Knative components installed to your cluster.

> And my next question would be, how to programmatically create Cloud Run services on GKE?

You will have a **very hard time** (if possible at all) using the Cloud Run API client libraries (e.g. `new CloudRun` above) because these are designed for `*.googleapis.com` endpoints.

The Knative API part of "Cloud Run on GKE" is actually just your Kubernetes (GKE) master API endpoint (which runs on an IP address, with a TLS certificate that isn't trusted by root CAs, but you can find the CA cert in GKE GetCluster API call to verify the cert.) The TLS is part is why it's so hard to use the API Client libraries.

Knative APIs are just Kubernetes objects. So your best bet is one of these:

- See Kubernetes java client (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) actually allows dynamic objects. (Go implementation does) and try to use that to create Knative CRDs.
- Use `kubectl apply`.
- Ask Knative Serving open source repository for help (they should be providing client libraries, maybe they're already there I'm not sure)

To program **Cloud Run (managed)** with the API Client Libraries, you need to explicitly override the API endpoint to the region e.g. `us-central1-run.googleapis.com`. (This is documented on each API call's REST API reference documentation.)

I have written a blog post in detail (with sample code in Go) on how to create/update services on Cloud Run (managed) using the Knative Serving API here: https://ahmet.im/blog/gcloud-run-deploy/

If you want to see how `gcloud run deploy` works, and which APIs it calls, you can pass `--log-http` option to observe the request/response traffic.

As for the error you got, it seems like the error message isn't helpful, but it might be coming from anywhere (as you're trying to imitate Knative API in GCP client libraries). I recommend reading my blog posts and sample code in depth.

---

**UPDATES:** Our engineering team's looking at the issue, it appears that there's currently a bug not adding the "details" field to the error. That's being worked on.

In your case, we see the following errors from requests:

```
field: "spec.template.spec"
  description: "Missing template spec."
```

Means you are not properly filling up the spec field as I shown in my blog post and sample code.

```
field: "metadata.name"
  description: "The revision name must be prefixed by the name of the enclosing Service or Configuration with a trailing -"
```

Make sure the name you are specifying adheres the patterns specified in API docs. Try to create that name manually perhaps in the UI or gcloud CLI.

```
field: "api_version"
  description: "Unsupported API version \'serving.knative.dev/v1\'. Expected \'serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1\'"
```

Do not use v1alpha1 API, use v1 directly.

We'll try to get the details to the error message, however it appears that  you need to study the sample code I linked in my blog post more in detail:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run-button/blob/a52c7fbaae33a3e06c112206c7227a0ef9649647/cmd/cloudshell_open/deploy.go#L26-L112

Comment: still no luck to create service to managed cloud run.   I'm thinking, it shouldn't be the way I create the Run client, as I can get managed services no problem.  To create a service tho (I'm using gcr.io/cloudrun/hello as the sample image now) to manged cloud run, I've done everything to set the Service object as you do in your Go implementation with both `com.google.api.services.run.v1alpha1` and `com.google.api.services.run.v1`, still invalid argument error :(

Comment: OK I'm adding some updates now to my answer above based on engineering team's queries of this error message.

Comment: Figured out the culprit is that the revision name that I put didn't follow the expected pattern. also, both v1alpha1 and v1 work, just that the maven package and the declared version in the service should be the same

Comment: Marked this question done. Will be moving onto figuring out GKE one

Answer (score 0):

The Java SDK is automatically generated from the fact that the Cloud Run (fully managed) API is public. It does not support Cloud Run for Anthos.

Answer (score 0):

(gcloud.run.deploy) The revision name must be prefixed by the name of the enclosing Service or Configuration with a trailing -[revision name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXRQi.png)

revision name name should be 65 character then problem will be resolved in Automation pipeline with GCP revision suffix should be less revision name is the combination of (service name +revision suffix) will automatically created by GCP.