# GCP Cloud Run API(SDK) - create a service programmatically

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Where can i find API(SDK) for GCP Cloud Run to create a service programmatically?
Is it exists? In development?
They are not here.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java

Or my one way is to call gcloud run from command line?
Or is it impossible? I do not see a command to create a service from the command line.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/services

Thanks for hints.

Comment: Creating a Cloud Run service programmatically is very challenging. I have written articles on this topic. The API is simple. The parameters required are complex. This question with its answers will point you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61357330/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the answer. Do i  understand correct, that this code is yours? Or it is Google SDK? CloudRun.Builder builder = new CloudRun.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer);             And the second question, did you solve your challenge? Did you created your Cloud Run service programmatically?

Comment: I do not understand your question. When I write code for my articles or as a Google GDE, I publish under the MIT license (which grants everyone rights for any purpose).

Comment: @JohnHanley Ahh, sorry. Didn't see a link to your article. I saw and from there I found a link to rest api. Somehow I overlooked it.
I found what I was looking for! https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/create
A bit not that, but still. I wanted not rest, but pure Java api, for example, like here https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/libraries. But that's great too.
Thank you!